# how to position the selected annotation in MKMapView to the bottom of the iPad screen

Tags: ios

in iOS 5.0, iPad, in MKMapview, once the user has selected a place from a give table list of places, I need to move the annotation for that place on the MKMapview so that it appears towards the bottom of the screen..

so I cannot just call setCenterCoordinate using the location of the annotation, as that will centre this annotation on the screen whereas I need to make the annotation appear towards the bottom of the screen .

How would I do this?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: or how to centre the map to a position which is say 10 miles to north of the selected poi annotation?

Comment: would doing something like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5306795/774691 (found in the "Related" sidebar) solve your problem?

Comment: it does not, as i need to ensure that the selected poi annotation is at a specific point at the bottom of the screen.. and the poi being set to the screen bottom should be animated smoothly.. the above code only shifts the visible rect relative to the poi and not to the screen.. I hope this explains my problem..