# Swift 3.0 mapkit didSelect moves MKMapView to left

Tags: swift, swift3, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I'm working on a project with swift 3.0 and a mapkit.

Now I want to touch a Annotation

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
             didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
{

    print("Annotation touched!");


}
```

but when I touch an Annotation the map moves to the left.

[image from the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poH60.png)

I hope you can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: You need to move the MKMapView based on selected annotation. [refer this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306392/how-to-move-mkmapview-based-on-selected-annotation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a button in your annotation:

```
    let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)  // The size of the button.
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: smallSquare))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.a_function_where_you_can_put_anything), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    your_pin?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
```

Attention! **You should put this code when you initialize the annotation.**

For exemple:

```
let reuseId = "pin"
var your_pin = your_map.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
// Your pin

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: smallSquare))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.a_function_where_you_can_put_anything), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    your_pin?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
```

Like this, a button is initialized in the annotation and, when the user's selects it, the function a_function_where_you_can_put_anything () (in my exemple) is calling. I give you an exemple of this function:

```
func a_function_where_you_can_put_anything () {      // This function is calling  when the button was selected.

   print ("Annotation touched!");

}
```

However, the button only works on the left of the annotation. You can have a picture for signalize to the user's the button: `your_pin.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "your_image"), forState: .Normal)`.

You can have more details in [apple developer web site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html).

This code is less beautiful than your's but it works.

Cordially.

Comment: thanks for your help! but this is not the solution. the code is now : 

`  didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
    {
        let smallSquare = CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)  // The size of the button.
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: smallSquare))
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.test), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button
        
       print("Annotation touched!");
        
        
}`

the map was before I touch an Annotation the full with.

Comment: Excuse me, my precedent post was not very clear. You should put the code when you initialize your annotation. You should, also, replace, your function to a another function which is calling when the button was selected.